# Why doesn't this function work?

Tags: javascript, html, scope

When i click "test" to frame is resized but when i click it again it doesnt resize back to its original size

```
function dropdownResize(){

var down = 0;

        if(down == 0){
                parent.document.getElementById('frameMain').rows = '84,84,*';
                down = 1;
            }
        else{
                parent.document.getElementById('frameMain').rows = '84,30,*';
                down = 0;
            }


    }
```

```
<a onclick="dropdownResize()"> test</a>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It does not work because `down` is **defined within the scope of the function `dropdownResize()`**. When the function is called, `down` is reset to 0 every time again.

**What you should do:** *(please note that this is a direct answer to your question and you should probably learn more about [variable scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/javascript-variable-scope) in order to prevent global variables as much as possible)*

```
var down = 0;
function dropdownResize(){
        if(down == 0){
                parent.document.getElementById('frameMain').rows = '84,84,*';
                down = 1;
            }
        else{
                parent.document.getElementById('frameMain').rows = '84,30,*';
                down = 0;
            }
    }
```

Comment: I'd mention something about scope collision, if I wasn't lazy.  But I am - so this'll be good enough, haha.

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
var down = 0;

function dropdownResize(){

        if(down == 0){
                parent.document.getElementById('frameMain').rows = '84,84,*';
                down = 1;
            }
        else{
                parent.document.getElementById('frameMain').rows = '84,30,*';
                down = 0;
            }


    }
```

Comment: I'm curious what .rows 'num,num,*' mean. can you share a sample on jsfiddle

Comment: @Ab: It's to do with frames, look up `frameset` on google. They are usually considered bad practise now, so it slightly worries me what this guy is doing.

Answer (score 1):

I think down is a local variable and will be set to 0 each time the function is called.